# Substrate-Archive, workaround for MAC?

Tags: substrate-archive, indexing, archive

Setting up [Substrate-Archive](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive) for the first time. Tutorial/Wiki is a bit outdated. Following [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive/issues/423) solution that I found in "issues". Compiled and ran; however, I got an issue that I believe is MAC related.

Solution:

`1. Run docker-compose up -d to start postgres and pgadmin`

`2. Run DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:123@localhost:6432/local_chain_db sqlx database create in substrate-archive/src to create the database.`

`` 3. Run DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:123@localhost:6432/local_chain_db sqlx migrate run in substrate-archive/src` to create the tables. ``

`4. Run cargo run --release -- -c archive.toml in bin/node-template-archive/ to start indexing. Keep in mind to modify the archive.toml configs.`

Ran step 4 and received the following error:

Error:

`` Error: Failed to create RocksDB directory: `Os { code: 30, kind: ReadOnlyFilesystem, message: "Read-only file system" }`. ``

Is there a workaround? Thank you.

Comment: The a "Read-only file system" error when trying to run the code sounds to me like it does not have the ability to write to some directory it needs to; I'd check your filesystem permissions on any directories mentioned in the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Incorrectly modified the archive.toml file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).